# ObjectSet library is not being found?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-4.0, objectset

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using ModelLayer.PocoModels;
using System.Data.Objects;

namespace ModelLayer
{
    public class NorthwindDataContext : ObjectContext
    {
        private ObjectSet<Category> _categories;
        private ObjectSet<Product> _products;
        public NorthwindDataContext()
            : base("name=NorthwindEntities",
                "NorthwindEntities")
        {
            _categories = CreateObjectSet<Category>();
            _products = CreateObjectSet<Product>();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I get an error as it cant find the `ObjectSet` class and gives me type or namespace not found error.While in the sample project it works fine it is under using `System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet` but I dont see that library in my current project?  I am using asp.net mvc and .net 4.0. Does anyone have any good ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your project has a reference to `System.Data.Entity`.

You may also need references to `System.Runtime.Serialization` and `System.Security`.

Visual Studio adds these for you automatically when you add an EDMX file (ADO.NET Entity Data Model) to your project.

Comment: Got it..it was for some reason using .net 3.5..my bad :(