# How to set the "Target Framework" in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I am new to C# programming and don't know how to set the "Target Framework" in visual studio 2013? When I right click on the project -> Properties I see no left column of the property pages window with no Application tab.
I tried to build a solution and I got several errors like this:

> Error 6 The type or namespace name 'ObjectSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And then I found this answer
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567945/type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist)

But I don't actually know how to change the target framework. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

[EDIT]
Screenshot. I use Visual Studio Professional 2013
[image: Visual Studio]

Comment: Is your project using entity framework?

Comment: yes, I installed it with "Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.2" in console manager

Comment: What **do** you see?  Getting started with the wrong project template, like a Portable Class Library, or using the Express edition of VS2013 are simple explanations that we can't eliminate unless you tell us what you see.

Comment: I imported a project and tried to build the solution.. the project was working on my colleague's laptop, he is using visual studio 2010.. Maybe I forgot to do something prior to build the solution. I opened the project, installed the entity framework and I am trying to make it work [screenshot added]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right Click a project > click properties > first tab -> Target Framework

[image]

[image]

Comment: ohh ok thanks, I tried to right click on the folder.. thank you

Comment: I run my console app into Windows Server 2003 (max supported .NET Framework = 4.0), but if i choose .NET Framework 4.0 in Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 it does not matter and i get error You must install .NET Framework 4.5...

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the error it seems like you are missing reference to dlls.
Please look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787065/objectset-library-is-not-being-found)

Comment: the references are added