# Visual Studio 2013 not showing .net Framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, frameworks, .net-4.5

I have been trying to figure out how to install the .net framework 4.5.2 for visual studio. I heard that visual studio already has 4.5 installed, but it's not showing up on my list, the highest is version 3.5.  I have been to many websites and installed the framework from these locations:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

```
                                       ^^^     =40773

                                       ^^^     =42637
```

None of these have worked, I am still stuck with 3.5, which is extremely frustrating. 
Thanks :)
Sam

Comment: You need to see in HELP->About Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Ok, I've looked there and it's telling me that it is using version 4.5. But when I go to publish, it only goes up to 3.5

Comment: You probably need to change the targeted version before publishing your website.
Need to go to the Property Pages of the Project -->Build->Target Framework

Comment: Ok, when I click project, build is not an option.

Comment: Property Pages -->Build->Target Framework

Comment: When I click build, nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

I have shown this in below image. Please try to follow:

[image]
[image]

OR You need to follow this (the winning answer) [`How to set the “Target Framework” in visual studio 2013`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078058/how-to-set-the-target-framework-in-visual-studio-2013?answertab=active#tab-top)

OR

Once can set this using Web.Config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as I previously mentioned, I cannot change the target framework to 4 or above, which is why I am seeking help.

Comment: Hope it solved your problem.
Request you to accept as a answer.

Comment: Erm, I think you misread what I said. All your picture illustrates is my issue, not a solution.

Comment: Hold on, all we have tried is to solve your problem. These pictures showed you how to and from here you can able to change your targeted framework and nothing else.

Comment: My issue, is that I can't change it to 4+, and all that the pictures show is you changing yours to 4+. I can't.

Comment: Can you show me a step by step screenshot that you have done?

Comment: can you find list of .net framework installed in ur pc

`%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework`

`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework`  `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx`

Comment: Yeah, I have a folder called 4.0.3

Comment: Here you can find [`.NET 4.5`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225702) offline version. Download and install it.

Comment: After installing it, reboot the PC. After opening VS you should probably see the updated .net framework version.

Comment: Alright, I tried all of that and it's still not there. I even uninstalled an reinstalled visual studio, reinstalled .net framework, and reinstalled developer frameworks. Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

- Go to the Project menu and click on the Properties menu item
- Click on Application in the left pane
- In the target framework drop down, make sure it is set to .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't fix my issue. As I have already said the option for 4.5 is not there, which is why I'm seeking help.

Comment: When I answered your question above, I was running Visual Studio Express 2012. I have since uninstalled it. I downloaded and ran Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. I still see .NET Framework 4.5 available in the drop down. You likely don't have .NET Framework installed or have corrupted files. Uninstall .NET and redownload and install again.